# How can I extract an object from an http request response using python

Tags: python, json, http

I have an http response that looks like the one below, I want to use python to create a dataframe of the data included in the Premier league standings.

So I am looking for Team: Manchester City, Rank: 1
etc....

I usually work in JS where you can use dot notation but this doesn't seem to work in python

```
{
"get":"standings",
"parameters":{
"league":"39",
"season":"2022"
},
"errors":[
],
"results":1,
"paging":{
"current":1,
"total":1
},
"response":[
{
"league":{
"id":39,
"name":"Premier League",
"country":"England",
"logo":"https:\/\/media-2.api-sports.io\/football\/leagues\/39.png",
"flag":"https:\/\/media-1.api-sports.io\/flags\/gb.svg",
"season":2022,
"standings":[
[
{
"rank":1,
"team":{
"id":50,
"name":"Manchester City",
"logo":"https:\/\/media-2.api-sports.io\/football\/teams\/50.png"
},
"points":89,
"goalsDiff":61,
"group":"Premier League",
"form":"LDWWW",
"status":"same",
"description":"Promotion - Champions League (Group Stage: )",
"all":{
"played":38,
"win":28,
"draw":5,
"lose":5,
"goals":{
"for":94,
"against":33
}
},
"home":{
"played":19,
"win":17,
"draw":1,
"lose":1,
"goals":{
"for":60,
"against":17
}
},
"away":{
"played":19,
"win":11,
"draw":4,
"lose":4,
"goals":{
"for":34,
"against":16
}
},
"update":"2023-05-28T00:00:00+00:00"
},
{
"rank":2,
"team":{
"id":42,
"name":"Arsenal",
"logo":"https:\/\/media-2.api-sports.io\/football\/teams\/42.png"
},
"points":84,
"goalsDiff":45,
"group":"Premier League",
"form":"WLLWW",
"status":"same",
"description":"Promotion - Champions League (Group Stage: )",
"all":{
"played":38,
"win":26,
"draw":6,
"lose":6,
"goals":{
"for":88,
"against":43
}
},
"home":{
"played":19,
"win":14,
"draw":3,
"lose":2,
"goals":{
"for":53,
"against":25
}
},
"away":{
"played":19,
"win":12,
"draw":3,
"lose":4,
"goals":{
"for":35,
"against":18
}
},
"update":"2023-05-28T00:00:00+00:00"
}
]
]
}
}
]
}
```

I have played around with pandas, pd.dataframe and iloc[x] but still cannot extra the data I want.

Comment: This is three different questions. Focus on one. If you want to get a POST payload, there's a million webpages that tell you how, already. If you want to know how to turn this data into a native python object, looking up "parsing json in python", and if you want to know how to access properties, also look up "parsing json in python" to find out what data structure that yields, and how you work with those in python.